# Force pull request to specific branch

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I want that all pull request on GitHub will be to dev branch without making it the default branch.

Is there a way to do it? If I do it, do I need to adjust the fork source too?

** edit **
I'm talking about contributers push, not my own.